# How can I customize the filter form onChange behaviour in the list view of react-admin

Tags: react-admin

The default behaviour of the filters in the list view of react-admin is to filter the list and cause an API call (presumably submit the form) on every change to the filter inputs. I would like an API call only to happen when an input onBlurs or when an explicit 'Search' button is clicked.

I have been playing with the onChange, onBlur functions of the inputs and the Filter, preventDefault, setFilters ... Nothing has come close to working but I include some template code below.

Perhaps I'd like to be able to specify the redux-form touchOnChange and touchOnBlur props but don't see any way of doing that.

How can this be achieved?

```
import { Filter, TextInput } from react-admin;
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';

const MyFilter = (props) => {
    return ( <Filter {...props} onChange={()=>{}}>
        <TextInput label="Search" source="q" alwaysOn onBlur={()=>{}}/>
        <Button alwaysOn onClick={(event)=>(props && props.setFilters(props.filterValues))}>SEARCH</Button>
        <TextInput source="name"/>
    </Filter> )
  }
```

Comment: any luck?, as i m also looking for the same?